# Weird issue occurred when calling object's method inside redux-saga

Tags: redux-saga

I wrote a ApiArticle which is extend from ApiBase class, then I write a getArticles function inside ApiArticle like following:

```
getArticles(url) {
    // change the url.....
    return this.defaultGet(url);
}
```

If I need to fetch data, I simply do the following then it will work.

```
const apiArticle = new ApiArticle();
apiArticle.getArticles();
```

It works fine when I just fetch data at redux's action. But now I tried to learn redux-saga.
So I change the fetch data part into this:

```
function* fetchAllArticles(action) {
  const apiArticles = new ApiArticles();
  const url = `/article-management/articles`;
  const res = yield call(apiArticles.getArticles, url);
  yield put(fetchAllArticlesSuccess(res.data.articles));
}
```

Then I get error:
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultGet' of null**

But if I hard code the defaultGet without calling then it will work.

```
getArticles(url) {
    // change the url.....
    return axios.get(url).....
}
```

Seems like 'this' can't be work when using the redux-saga, how to fix it?

Comment: also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 0):

If you need the `call` effect to invoke the function with a specific value of `this`, you'll need to tell it that. There are a few different ways to do so, which you can find [in their documentation](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api#callcontext-fn-args), but one example is to pass an array as the first argument. The first element of the array specifies what `this` should be, the second specifies what function to call.

```
const res = yield call([apiArticles, apiArticles.getArticles], url);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'm watching the documentation now. I changed the res just like your answer but still get the same error. Is there something I doing wrong?